# Common-used packages for robot control

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, stacks, ros-kinetic, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Few days ago I found out `ROS Control` pacakge. Are there any other widly-used typical packages\stacks for common robot control tasks, such as robot joints control, inverse kinematics (MoveIt! maybe), visualization robot in RViz etc? Maybe there is some full index of ros packages\stacks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283988/common-used-packages-for-robot-control/) by [markovalexey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27531/markovalexey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a lot of packages. You can browse them here: http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php?package_type=package&distro=indigo

A common metric for how commonly used a package is to look at how many dependencies it has on it from their wiki page side bar "Used By" count. (It's better for libraries than applications though.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markovalexey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27531/markovalexey/) on 2018-03-01**:
I can't find this "used by" block. Where it is?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-03-01**:
On the right side bar of package wiki pages. eg http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager_msgs

**Comment by [markovalexey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27531/markovalexey/) on 2018-03-01**:
Thank you!